# Claimed problems with Lisp dynamic scoping

Tags: stacks, variable-binding, lisp

What would be the problem of running the following scala codes assuming we are working with dynamic scoping and a global stack to store environments as some variants of Lisp do?

```
def fact(n:Int,f:() => Int):Int = 
 if(n == 0) f()
 else fact(n-1,() => n*f())
fact(7,() => 1)



def incrementer(x:Int)  = y => y+x
incrementer(2)(3)
```

Comment: Have you tried to run them on paper? Just pass lambdas as they are, without closing their free variables in any way. From a cursory look, the first should get stuck in an infinite loop, while the second accesses an undefined variable `x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `fact`, the primary problem is with `f`.  If `n` is `0`, then it works fine.  However, for any other value of `n`, `fact` is called with an `f` of `() => n * f()`.  So when the base case (`n = 0`) is finally encountered, `f` is `() => n * f()`.  When `f` is invoked, `f` is still `() => n * f()`.  So the call to `f` results in unbounded recursion with itself.

With `incrementer`, `x` will be not be defined when `y => x + y` is called in your example.  This is because `y => x + y` does not close over `x` (because of dynamic, as opposed to lexical, binding), there is no call on the stack that binds `x` to a value when the closure is invoked, and there is no global / top-level binding for `x`.